# Showing near "total_entries" in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using RoR 2.3.8

Usually we have the following code:

```
Showing <%= @shops.total_entries %> shops in Canada.
```

yields the result:

```
Showing 46 shops in Canada
```

What if I want it to show round-down value:

```
Showing 40+ shops in Canada
```

Whereas for <10 total entries, it should show the exact number.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def round(total)
  total > 10 && total%10 != 0 ? [total/10*10,"+"].join : total.to_s
end

Showing <%= round(@shops.total_entries) %> shops in Canada.
```

and of course it would be better to wrap it as a Model method

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.round
    total = count
    total > 10 && total%10 != 0 ? [total/10*10,"+"].join : total.to_s
    # instead of using `[total/10*10,"+"].join` you can use `(total/10*10).to_s+"+"`
  end
end

@shops = Shop.were(:region => "Canada")

Showing <%= @shops.round %> shops in Canada.
```